# Ajax Request in the same domain using jQuery

Tags: json, jquery, getjson

I have a question where my client is on http://web-dev.test.com and my MVC Services are on http://webdev01.test.com . So i am trying to use ajax GET and POST json requests from my client to mvc services but it is giving me cross domain error. Can anyone explain me what the problem is? and how I could resolve this?

Thankyou

Comment: You'll need to use `$.ajax` with the jsonp option, not json.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can you also tell me if $.ajaxSetup works on the jsonp? - @JonathanM

Comment: +1ed you earlier for good question, I think this can be tricky as subdomains are also effected by the same origin policy and that may not be as obvious unless the docs are fully read as that info is quite far down in the docs :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

- Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the [**same origin policy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy); the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.
- Script and JSONP requests are not subject to the same origin policy restrictions.

Making it a JSONP request, if possible, should not cause you those issues. Otherwise I'm afraid you are not going to be able to successfully complete your request.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can you also tell me if $.ajaxSetup works on the jsonp?

Comment: I can't see anything in the documentation which would indicate any issues. The only direct influence I noticed in the docs is that when using JSONP the call must be asynchronous. Is there anything special in your setup code which would cause reasons for concern?

Comment: No my code does not have any synchronous calls. I was just curious if ajaxSetup method would fail by this change too. Thank you very much your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options using [`JSONP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) or [`CORS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

For CORS you set http headers for your service so that you client will have access to it, eg

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://web-dev.test.com
```